# Installing software programmatically in background

Tags: c#

I trying to make an application that help me to install software on other PC, I am using this code but did not work unfortunately :

```
                string filename = "Java\\jre-6u24-windows-i586.exe";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i \"" + filename + "\" /qn";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();

            if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + output);
            }
```

> ERROR : T

Comment: "did not work unfortunately" - any exception?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Did you check the output of your process for error messages?

Comment: Wild guess: change that part `filename+"\" /qn";` to contain space between file name and `/qn`.

Comment: Can you output the ExitCode property?

Comment: @nvoigt I got result: 1620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`msiexec.exe`** is to install ***.msi-Files!**
Your `re-6u24-windows-i586.exe` is a standalone executeable.
Which must be assigned to the `p.StartInfo.FileName` property!

And the `p.StartInfo.Arguments` must contain the args this specific installer!  **`/qn`** are args for an MSI-package!

Answer (score 0):

To find out what's wrong, you need to get the output of your process:

```
string filename ="Java\\jre-6u24-windows-i586.exe";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i \""+filename+"\" /qn";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();

if(p.ExitCode != 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + output);
}
```

The error code you receive means

> ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID (1620)   This installation package could not be 
>   opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows 
>   Installer package.

So I guess this is not an msi package. Maybe you need to call the exe directly, without the use of msiexec?